# Is there a Passport Strategy to handle an offsite API which isn't OAuth?

Tags: express, passport.js

I've got a relatively unique use-case here and I can't find the perfect solution.

I have a website that has user log-in via facebook and linkedin, which works flawlessly via passportjs. 
However I also need to be able to login via an offsite API which is not OAuth but rather offers a standard JSON response.

I currently use angular to hit the API and return the user object but then I have to store that in sessionStorage to persist the log in. This isn't ideal as it means there is a server session and a local session. To log out I have to manually clear the sessionStorage and this hit a log out path for the server.

What I want to do is create a local log in path on the ExpressJS website and the route then hits the API to log in and then the user is stored in the server session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I hacked the local strategy.

The key was adding passReqToCallback so I could manipulate the request.

This adds the response to req.user and starts a session.

Strategy:

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy,
    request = require('request')

module.exports = function() {
    passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
            passReqToCallback: true
         },
         function(req, username, password, done) {
             request.post({
                url: 'http://api/',
                form: {
                    username: username,
                    password: password
                },
                json: true
            }, function(err, httpResponse, body) {
                if (err || !body.success) done();
                else done(null, body);
            });
        }
    ));
};
```

Route:

```
app.post('/auth/local',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        failureRedirect: '/fail'
    }),
    function(req, res) {
        res.redirect('/success');
    });
```